# excel multiple data onto one line

Tags: excel, if-statement, duplicates, concatenation

So I have data in the following layout

```
     April    May     June      July     August
a       1
a              4
a                       7
a              
a                                         2
b    1
c              1
c                       3
```

and need it in the following format:

```
     April    May     June   July    August
 a    1        4       7              2
 b    1
 c              1       3
```

I have tried various if statements but cant get them all in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

**ASSUMPTIONS**
Your data are starting in cell A1

**Formulas**

1. set a column name to your column A
2. Assuming we use your dataset (you will have to adapt if you want the full year) In cell G1 type the formula `=A1` and copy /paste to range H1 to L1. Set in G2 the formula `=A2`
3. IN cell G3, type `=IF(A3=A2;"";A3)` and copy this formula all the way down your dataset in column G
4. In cell H2 type `=SUMIF($A:$A;$G2;B:B)`
5. Copy the formula of H2 horizontally in your row 2 from H2 to L2 (based on your sample dataset)
6. Copy vertically the formula in all rows of your dataset in the range H3:L3 to Hn:Ln

Then you can set a filter on the first row and filter out blank values from column G:G... that does the job... and a copy / paste special Values would give you a clean data set....

Hope that helps

regards

Comment: I wanted to do it using formulas rather than the filter process, this is because it will be accepting new and different data (i.e. a, b, c represent individualised references)..

Comment: Then you should use another approach, if possible, which would be to have your source data as just a list with 3 values, Reference / Month / Count and then you use a PIVOT TABLE for the presentation.... With formulas, you will not be able to reduce the number of rows. If you want this keeping the same level, then you need to write a VBA script to do the job...